# Grails - tell if object can be deleted

Tags: hibernate, grails

In my application, in one transaction there are some domain objects that I want to delete, and some to update:

```
       Advertiser.withTransaction {
        batch.each {  record ->
            if (recordsShouldBeDeleted(record))
                record.delete()
            else 
                record.save()
           }
        }
```

I know that some of them are a parent key to a different table, so I shouldn't be able to delete them.
I want that for now, in the loop, if the record can not be deleted nothing should happen and I would take care of them later. But as it's now, the whole transaction fails because of one record.

Is there a way to know, before I try do delete the object, if I would be able to do so, then I would know not to try to delete these certain object although my `recordsShouldBeDeleted` return true? (something like `validate()` method that checks constrains?)

Or there is any other idea for the situation?

Thanks.

Comment: So it's more like a 'recordCouldBeDeleted' (without raising any constraint breaks) check?

Comment: Maybe, But what could I check there?

Comment: Have a look at this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294669/nhibernate-how-to-find-if-a-referenced-object-can-be-deleted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is surround the code with a try / catch block and if the delete fails, do nothing. 
Maybe it's not the best approach, but I haven't found still a reason for not doing it this way.

```
Advertiser.withTransaction {
    batch.each {  record ->
        if (recordsShouldBeDeleted(record))
            try{
                record.delete()
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        else 
            record.save()
       }
    }
```